# Which resolutions should I make a favicon in?

Tags: performance, favicon

I understand that you can create a [`favicon.ico`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) with multiple resolutions embedded.

Which resolutions should your average website support?  Why?

Edit: Performance should be a consideration. I want to keep the favicon around 1K to stay inline with these recommendations: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Favicons in the browser are 16x16 pixels. For multiple resolution favicons, the sizes 24x24, 32x32, and 48x48 pixels are the most common to include in addition.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommends including a 16x16 pixel and a 24x24 pixel favicon (for when the user's system-wide DPI setting is higher than 100%).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc849094(VS.85).aspx#Favicons

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/favicon.html) helps to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, it does.  Though, the author of this article recommends that you create a favicon for every resolution and then at multiple color depths for each resolution.

The downside to this strategy would be performance:
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: It would help if you quoted the relevant part of the page you've linked to. It helps keep the knowledge here and guards against "link rot".